# ELMAH - is it possible to log errors AS WELL AS send e-mail manually through code?

Tags: elmah

I know Elmah can be used to manually log errors much like log4net can be used. However, is it possible to log a caught exception as well as e-mail the exception at the same time much like it does for unhandled exceptions.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this Q is YES.

```
Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new Exception("logs it to ELMAH as well as it sends an email"));
```